# jQuery Galleria - How to add the youtube video title to the autoplay

Tags: jquery, youtube, galleria, autoplay

I have Galleria autoplay here on my webpage: http://www.clickclack.cz/. I want to add the youtube video title (there are only youtube videos). Can you help me, how to do that?

My settings are here:

```
    $(function() {
    Galleria.loadTheme('galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');          
    Galleria.run('#galleria', {
        _toggleInfo: false,
        extend: function() { 
            var gallery = this; 

            gallery.play(); 
            var paused = 0; 
            this.$('stage').hover(function() { 
                if (paused) { 
                    $(this).data('overTime', '1');
                } else { 
                    paused = 1; 
                    gallery.pause(); 
                    $(this).data('overTime', new Date().getTime()); 
                } 
            }, function() { 
                var outTime = new Date().getTime(); 
                var hoverTime = (outTime - $(this).data('overTime'))/1000;
                if (hoverTime < 0.5) { // restart slideshow if hover under 0.5 seconds 
                    paused = 0; 
                    gallery.play(); 
                } 
            }); 
        } 
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found the solution. In JS I added

```
youtube: {
            modestbranding: 1,
            autohide: 1,
            color: 'white',
            hd: 1,
            rel: 0,
            showinfo: 1
        }
```

showInfo: 1 displays the name of the video as it is on youtube.